# how to switch-case with inconsistent variable format

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
switch (req.path)
{
    case "/api/posts": 
        console.log("posts");
    break;

    case "/api/posts/tags/*": // the part * is always changing depending on user input
        console.log("tags");
    break;

    case "/api/best": 
        console.log("best"); 
    break;

    default: 
        console.log("default");
}
```

the req.path gives my path

for example

```
/api/post/tags/asd,dsfd
/api/post/tags/1
/api/post/tags/12,123
```

how do you manage with this as efficiently as possible?

some frameworks provide path parsers that looks like

```
/*
```

this and any input after * is ignored and treated as the same. I am curious of its inner mechanism.

Comment: Use an `if-else` or switch on a `substring`.

Comment: Yeah, just use a `startsWith` kind of thing. Otherwise regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64acqcqk/)):

```
function route(req) {
    if(req.path === '/api/posts') {
        console.log('posts');
    }

    if(req.path.indexOf('/api/posts/tags') > -1) {
        console.log('tags');
    }

    // etc.
}

route({path: '/api/posts'}); // => posts
route({path: '/api/posts/tags/hi'}); // => tags
route({path: '/api/posts/tags/cool'}); // => tags
```

You could also use a regular expression. Keep in mind that if some input conditions might match each other, you'll want to `return` at the end of each `if` statement, or simply use `else if`. Totally depends on the routes your looking for.

For the `default` case, you can string together everything with `if... else if`, and in the final `else` put `console.log('default')`. I've left my above solution very minimal so you can extend it as you see fit.

## Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can just toss a regex into your switch statement which will handle all cases branching off of that route.

```
switch (req.path)
{
    case "/api/posts": 
        console.log("posts");
    break;

    case req.path.match(/(\/api\/posts\/tags\/)/)[1]:
        console.log("tags");
    break;

    case "/api/best": 
        console.log("best"); 
    break;

    default: 
        console.log("default");
}
```